# Is it possible to do automation testing for QML using squish?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, qml, squish

I need to know if squish is built to test QML standalone applications? I know it can test Qt standalone applications.But i am unable to do the same for QML specifically.

Comment: I too need same answer..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, squish can test QML standalone application. What version of squish you used? I have tested squish with my QML application few months ago, and it works well.

Please refer to the related news for squish:
http://www.prweb.com/releases/2013/9/prweb11160262.htm